# load and perfomance testing from Multiple location using coded ui

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, coded-ui-tests, msloadtest

I need to load and performance test 500 virtual users load with 5 different locations so can I do it with microsoft coded ui.

Load and performance testing from a different location is important in my case. can someone suggest if it possible with coded ui or some other tools they can do it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is there a specific question here?

Comment: can I run a coded UI test from different USA locations?

Comment: Hm, you do know coded UI testss are deprecated? And there are plenty of services that can run international tests?

Comment: To run 500 users with Coded UI needs 500 computers. Are you really planning to use Coded UI? Load testing with Visual Studio almost never uses Coded UI

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no(you can but it won't make any sense to use 500 different machines as coded UI uses active desktop). Coded UI tool is used for UI test automation. Also, coded UI is deprecated.

But you can do performance testing using visual studio. refer below link for more details on the same.

[Performance testing using visual studiio](http://can%20I%20run%20a%20coded%20UI%20test%20from%20different%20USA%20locations?%20%E2%80%93%20Hrishabh%20Kushwah%20May%205%20at%204:50)